# Bring parent window to front when child window selected from taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, window, focus, parent-child

The title pretty much says it all, but basically I have a main parent window, which occasionally opens child windows.  Right now it's possible to select one of the child windows from the Windows 7 taskbar, and only that window will be brought to the front.  What I'd like it to find a way to link the parent window to this command, so that any time a child window is selected the parent is automatically brought to the front as well.

I tried to use both the `Focus()` and `Topmost = true` commands from within the child windows 'GotFocus`event handler, but neither seemed to make a difference.  I also tried the`BringIntoView()` method, but again, no joy.  Has anyone seen this before or know a way to implement this?

This is what I've tried so far.  The logic in setting `mainWindow` first and then immediately setting the child window is that I do still want the child window to have focus, but I want `mainWindow` to be above any other programs running (ie-Excel, VS, etc).

```
    private void Window_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow) as MainWindow;

        mainWindow.Topmost = true;
        this.Topmost = true;

    }
```

Comment: Just tried it, no change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're listening to the wrong event to be notified when your window is selected. Subscribe to the `Activated` event on your child window which should let you know when your window is selected in the taskbar. From there you can Activate() your MainWindow.

Additionally, I think if you set the parent window to be the Owner of the child window you'll get this behavior automatically.

Comment: I don't know about the `Activated` even, but setting the `MainWindow` as owner was exactly right.  I knew this was possible, just couldn't place the terminology.  Thanks for giving my brain a jump-start.  :)